# ImportError: No module named enum on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I'm running a code with Python 2.7. And I get "ImportError: No module named enum". I installed enum with "pip install enum" but the error keeps coming. What shall I do??

Comment: type `pip show enum` in the command prompt and see what it says under "Requires"

Comment: it shows nothing!

Answer (score 16):

You want the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34):

```
pip install enum34
```

The distribution named `enum` on PyPI is something else, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

The `enum` module is part of Python 3.4 (and later) stdlib but *not* part of Python 2.7 stdlib.

Fortunately, there's an available backport suitable to Python 2.7. Install it and play with it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34