# Max key from other dictionary values function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}
```

I get values from a different program that gives a dictionary like this

```
my_values = {'Web': OK, 'Host': WARN, 'System': FATAL}
```

Now I want to compare value from *my_values* with keys of *stats* and get the highest result.

For example:

if *my_values = {'Web': OK, 'Host': WARN, 'System': FATAL}* fuction should return *FATAL*

if *my_values = {'Web': OK, 'Host': WARN, 'System': ERROR}* fuction should return *ERROR*

if *my_values = {'Web': OK, 'Host': WARN, 'System': WARN}* fuction should return *WARN*

So far I got till here, it only gives max values of a give dict.

```
import operator

def high_value(my_value):
    stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}

    print max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

high_value (my_values)
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this python 3.x when you're using `iteritems` which doesn't even exist in Python 3?

Comment: Do you want to return the value instead of printing? What is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can change it to a lambda:

```
import operator

def high_value(my_value):
    stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}
    return max(my_value.items(), key=lambda x: stats.get(x[1])) )

my_values = {'Web': "OK", 'Host': "WARN", 'System': "FATAL"}

print(high_value(my_values))
```

Output:

```
('System', 'FATAL')
```

If you just want `'FATAL'`, you do not even need a lambda, `dict.get` is enough if you operate on `my_value.values()`:

```
def high_value(my_value):
    stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}
    return max(my_value.values(), key=stats.get)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a class with constants like this

```
class STATS(object):
    OK = 0
    SKIP = 1
    EXCEPTION = 2
    FATAL = 3

    LABELS = {
        OK: "Ok",
        FATAL: "Fatal"
    }
```

And use it as such:

```
myvals = {"Web": STATS.FATAL}
result = STATS.LABELS[myvals["Web"]]
print(result)
```

Comment: Why would you make a class here? Not to mention that your example dict uses a name, not a string, so will throw errors

Comment: These are called [enums](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/enum.html) and there is a [backport of the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731222/importerror-no-module-named-enum-on-python-2-7) for it in py2.7

Comment: Enums could also work yes, this was my first idea. Nice @TemporalWolf I didn't know they are available in python 2 as well. Awesome hint.

Comment: @roganjosh I updated my answer with some labels for those constants.

Comment: My point was more what you're doing has a standard name, [enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type). This is a fine implementation if you don't need the advanced features of the enum backport.

Answer (score 0):

Just Iterate `my_values` dict to find the maximum value by comparing `stats` dict

```
import operator
stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}
my_values = {'Web': 'OK', 'Host': 'WARN', 'System': 'FATAL'}
value_string, max_value='', -1
for k,v in my_values.items():
    if max_value< stats[v]:
        max_value=stats[v]
        value_string=k
print(value_string,max_value)
```

**Output**

```
('System', 5)
```

If you need all the info then

```
stats = {'OK':0, 'SKIP':1, 'EXCEPTION':2, 'WARN':3, 'ERROR':4, 'FATAL':5}
my_values = {'Web': 'OK', 'Host': 'WARN', 'System': 'FATAL'}
status,component, max_value='','', -1
for k,v in my_values.items():
    if max_value< stats[v]:
        max_value=stats[v]
        component=k
        status=v
print(component,max_value,status)
```

**Output**

```
('System', 5, 'FATAL')
```